# Android Device Monitor - empty File Explorer view

Tags: android, android-studio

I have spent hours with google and stackoverflow searching for tips how to  get it fixed with no luck. The solution maybe as easy as one, two, three but I just cannot get it.
Problem:
when I open Android Device Monitor I can see my device and all the apps on it on the left hand side of the window but when I the File Explorer tab on the right is empty and does not show any files. Unfortunately I am not able to post screenshots but I hope the description is clear enough . Not sure what happened as all was ok a few weeks ago. In the meantime I have updated Android Studio to 1.2.2 but I don't think it really matters. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem however, I can navigate into the file system by running the adb shell via the windows command line. so open up command line on windows, cd into appData > Local>Android>sdk >platform-tools and then abd shell
i think this is one way to get the file or the contents.